# Connecting to an horizontally scaled SQL database in different scenarios

Tags: c#, database, scalability

I have built a web service in C#/WebApi2. It is completely REST based, and scales horizontally very easily with a load balancer in front of it since it has no state itself.

However, I'm looking for info/solution on how to handle the database scalability, and I would like to start without focusing on any particular technology, more specific, I would like to use Dapper ORM In combination with multiple DB's if possible.

For example, I can connect to a PostgreSQL using Dapper and the NGPSQL ADO.NET driver, but, are there components which handle the case of having one master PGSQL database and four slaves to read from? Are there already C# components that handle these situations, where you can have connections to all of these DB's and depending on the operation it chooses either the master in case of write actions or slave in case of read and load balances over the slaves (since the number of reads will be significantly higher than the writes, this would be a fairly good solution).

What if I have a master - master situation? And what about similar situations with other DB's such as MS SQL with AlwaysOn for example, or MySQL cluster and it's variations? Is there any components to handle this kind of thing, and if not, does anybody have any pointers on documentation/lectures/blogs/tutorials on this topic. I cannot imagine I'm the first one to encounter this, and writing a completely custom made connection pool might be just re-inventing the wheel...

I know it is a general question, but I have the feeling there should have been done work regarding this topic, I just can find it. I know in cloud scenarios, Azure and AWS, you have solutions for this a specific load balancers, but, I would need this for an on-premise solution as well. Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to scale a database horizontally is to split your database into multiple databases - each having different set of data. Something like this:

Meta database (that has info on user, etc)
 - Database 1 (has data for first 100000 users)
 - Database 2 (has data for next 100000 users)
 - Database 3 (has data for next 100000 users)

Your API requests would route the query to the respective database based on info from Meta database.

This provides for scalability but not availability. Many multi-tenant SAAS apps use this structure.

Some references:
http://jamesgolick.com/2010/3/30/what-does-scalable-database-mean.html
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture